# Stopping Bitnami WAMP Apache and MySQL server through PowerShell script in Windows

Tags: mysql, powershell, apache, command-line, bitnami

I've trying to write a script to stop Apache and MySQL services in Bitnami WAMP. If we do manually, we have to open C:\WAMP\manager-windows.exe and stop the services like this:
[image]

However, when I go into command prompt and run the command "httpd -k start", the apache server starts running and I can access my web app but if I open manager-windows.exe again it doesn't reflect the change. I've been also trying to stop the Apache service using command prompt commands "httpd -k stop" but that is somehow conflicting with Apache web server when it is started through the manager-windows.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can use the servicerun.bat script we include in the installation directory to start/stop all the services at once.

```
servicerun.bat START
```

If you only want to start/stop Apache or MySQL using the command prompt, you can use the scripts we include at installdir/apache2/scripts/servicerun.bat or installdir/mysql/scripts/servicerun.bat